# MS Enterprise Library data access - Understanding SQL 'user connections' management

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, enterprise-library, connection-pooling

I'm trying to understand how MS Enterprise Library's data access block manages its connections to SQL. The issue I have is that under a steady load (from a load test), at 10 minute intervals the number of connections to SQL increases quickly - which causes noticeable jump in page response times from the website.

*This is the scenario I'm running:*

- Visual Studio load test tools, running against 3 web servers behind a load balancer

  - The tools give full visibility over the performance counters to all web + DB boxes
- The tests take ~10 seconds each, and perform 4 inserts (form data), and some trivial selects
- There are 60 tests running concurrently. There is no increase or decrease in load during the entire test.

  - The test is run for between 20 minutes and 3 hours, with consistent results.

*And this is the issue we see:*

- Exactly every 10 minutes, the performance counter from SQL for **SQL General: User Connections** increases - by ~20 connections total

  - The pages performing the HTTP post / DB insert are the ones most significantly affected. The other pages show moderate, but noticeable rises.
  - The CPU/memory load on the web servers is unaffected
- This increase corresponds with a notable bump in page response times - E.g. from .3 seconds average to up to 5 seconds
- After ~5 minutes it releases many of the connections, with no affect on web performance

  - The following 5 minutes of testing gives the same (normal) web performance
  - Ultimately, the graph looks like a [square wave](http://www.sfu.ca/sonic-studio/handbook/Square_Wave.html)
- Happens all over again, 10 minutes after the first rise

---

*What I've looked at:*

**Database calls:**

All calls in the database start with:

```
SqlDatabase database = new SqlDatabase([...]);
```

And execute either proc with no required output:

```
return database.ExecuteScalar([...], [...]);
```

Or read wrapped in a using statement:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)database.ExecuteReader([...], [...]))
{
    [...]
}
```

There are no direct uses of SqlConnection, no .Open() or .Close() methods, and no exceptions being thrown

**Database verification:**

We've run SQL profiler over the login / logout events, and taken snapshots with the [sp_who2](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/using-sp_who2) command, showing who owns the connections. The latter shows that indeed the web site (seen by machine + credential) are holding the connections.

There are no scheduled jobs (DB or web server), and the user connection load is stable when there is no load from the web servers.

**Connection pool config**

I know the min & max size of the connection pool can be altered with the connection string.

E.g.:

> "Data Source=[server];Initial Catalog=[x];Integrated Security=SSPI;**Max
>   Pool Size=75;Min Pool Size=5;**"

A fall back measure may be to set the minimum size to ~10

I understand the default max is 100, and the default min is 0 ([from here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/educate-yourself-about-net-sql-server-connection-string-syntax/6084879))

I'm a little bit lithe to think of connection pooling (specific to this setting) and the User Connections performance counter from SQL. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) introduces these connection pools as being used to manage connection string, which seems different to what I assume it does (hold a pool of connections generally available, to avoid the cost of re-opening them on SQL)

I still haven't seen any configuration parameters that are handily defaulting to 5 or 10 minutes, to zero in on...

---

So, any help is appreciated.

I know that 10 minute spikes sounds like a change in load, or new activity is happening - but we've worked quite hard to isolate those & any other factors - and for this question, I am hoping to understand EL scaling its connections up & down.

Thanks.

Comment: The thing I see upon quick inspection (tldr;) is that you're leaking connections when you return scalars.  You must do: object scalar; using (var db = ...) { scalar = db.Execute(...); } return scalar;  Oh ... and you might be leaking connections around your reader too.  You've only got the reader wrapped in using(), not the connection.  You might want to look into an IoC that automatically manages your connections, something like http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that SQL user connections are created & added to the pool whenever all other connections are busy. So when long-running queries occur, or the DB is otherwise unresponsive, it will choose to expand to manage the load.

The cause of this in our case happened to be a SQL replication job (unfortunate, but found...) - And the changes in the # of User Connections was just a symptom, not a possible cause.

Although the cause turned out to be elsewhere, I now feel I understand the connection pool management, from this (and assumably other) SQL libraries.